# Crontab has no access to docker commands

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, cron

Recently I started working on Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS machine. I have created a small project which should run from a docker container with command:

```
docker run docker_name "2022-04-11"
```

This command runs like a charm when I run it manually (I have `sudo` permissions), but breaks when I try to run it from `sudo crontab`.

I tried to log all output from the `crontab` to file `myjob.log` with command:

```
0 1 * * * docker run docker_name "2022-04-11" >> /home/projects/project/myjob.log 2>&1
```

Then I saw that `myjob.log` file contains an error message:

```
/bin/sh: 1: docker: not found
```

It got me confused. Why I can run `docker` commands, but `crontab` can't?

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Check you `crontab` you are probably missing something like:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO=root
```

If you are running as your *user* not `root` you have to add it to the top.

The short of it is that your `$PATH` isn't set so you can't find the `docker` command.

Comment: I pasted my `docker run` commad in `sudo crontab -e`, so command should be running with root permissions,

Comment: @neringab crontab does have a limited shell, that's what this answer is pointing at. Also see: https://serverfault.com/questions/449651/why-is-my-crontab-not-working-and-how-can-i-troubleshoot-it